# Cassandra Connector fails when run under Spark 2.3 on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, kubernetes, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to use the connector, which I've used a bunch of times in the past super successfully, with the new Spark 2.3 native Kubernetes support and am running into a lot of trouble.

I have a super simple job that looks like this:

```
package io.rhom

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf
import com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.ReadConf

/** Computes an approximation to pi */
object BackupLocations {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("BackupLocations")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(
      "fs.defaultFS",
      "wasb://<snip>"
    )

    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(
      "fs.azure.account.key.rhomlocations.blob.core.windows.net",
      "<snip>"
    )

    val df = spark
      .read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map( "table" -> "locations", "keyspace" -> "test"))
      .load()

    df.write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
      .save("wasb://<snip>")

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

which I'm building under SBT with Scala 2.11 and packaging with a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM timfpark/spark:20180305

COPY core-site.xml /opt/spark/conf

RUN mkdir -p /opt/spark/jars
COPY target/scala-2.11/rhom-backup-locations_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/spark/jars
```

and then executing with:

```
bin/spark-submit --master k8s://blue-rhom-io.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com:443  \
                             --deploy-mode cluster  \
                             --name backupLocations \
                             --class io.rhom.BackupLocations \
                             --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
                             --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.1.0.10 \
                             --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=timfpark/rhom-backup-locations:20180306v12 \
                              --jars https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/2.0.3-s_2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.3-s_2.11.jar,http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-azure/2.7.2/hadoop-azure-2.7.2.jar,http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/azure-storage/3.1.0/azure-storage-3.1.0.jar,http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-avro_2.11/4.0.0/spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar  \ 
                               local:///opt/spark/jars/rhom-backup-locations_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

all of this works except for the Cassandra connection piece, which eventually fails with:

```
2018-03-07 01:19:38 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.4.0.46, executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "user_id", "timestamp", "accuracy", "altitude", "altitude_accuracy", "course", "features", "latitude", "longitude", "source", "speed" FROM "rhom"."locations" WHERE token("user_id") > ? AND token("user_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/package$ScalaReflectionLock$
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:323)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:339)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:380)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/package$ScalaReflectionLock$
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ReflectionLock$.<init>(ReflectionLock.scala:5)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ReflectionLock$.<clinit>(ReflectionLock.scala)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.<init>(TypeConverter.scala:73)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.<clinit>(TypeConverter.scala)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:50)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:46)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.converterToCassandra(ColumnType.scala:231)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$11.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:312)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$11.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:312)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:312)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.package$ScalaReflectionLock$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 41 more

2018-03-07 01:19:38 INFO  TaskSetManager:54 - Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.4.0.46, executor 1, partition 0, ANY, 9486 bytes)
```

I've tried every thing I can possibly think of to resolve this - anyone have any ideas?  Is this possibly caused by another unrelated issue?

Comment: can you check that you have spark-sql as dependency?

Comment: spark-cassandra-connector 2.0.x is not compatible with 2.3. You need to use 2.3. Check the version compatibility here: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that version 2.0.7 of the Datastax Cassandra Connector does not support Spark 2.3 currently.  I opened a JIRA ticket on Datastax's site for this and hopefully it will be addressed soon.